# Extracting the values of a list as individual strings

Tags: python

Hi I have an issue in passing the values of a list as input in a form so it is interpolated as individual values.

I have a function Get_input which take two inputs.
I then want to define the inputs in a list and feed the list into a function.
My issue is that the list is always seen as one input in stead of two separate string values.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def Get_input(Date_start: str = '2020-01-01', Date_end: str = dt.date.today()):

    return pd.date_range(start=Date_start, end=Date_end)


Date_start='2021-11-01'
Date_end=str(dt.date.today())

input = [Date_start, Date_end]

Datetimes=Get_input(input)
```

So what I need is a way of defining Get_input(input) so it produces the same result as if I would input Get_input(Date_start, Date_end)

A solution will be very appreciated.

Comment: Change your argument to tuple, and operate it as tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The * is the operator you are looking for. So your call would look as follows:

`Datetimes=Get_input(*input)`

The operator seems to be referred to as "iterable unpacking" as you can see here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists

Same can be done with dicts, so if you have a dict with keys equal to the argument names of the method, you could call it via

`input = {'Date_start': 'some_date', 'Date_end': 'some_other_date'}`
`Datetimes=Get_input(**input)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Get_input(*input)
```

This unpacks your list as seperate arguments.